# event for Office JS Add-in width change?

Tags: angular, angular-material, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

We are using Angular with our OfficeJS Add-in.

As of now we don't have way to increase width of OfficeJS Add-in on or after load, so Add-in's content is getting loaded based on default width.

But, user can increase width manually, where based on width change I want to decide, how many number of [Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples) of same width can be displayed in Add-in (on width change), and want to control horizontal scroll behavior for rest of the width.

Core requirement is to trigger this behavior on manually changing of width by user.

So, do we have any way to get event for OfficeJS Add-in's width change?

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way. you should ideally be building reactive apps using media queries, mixins and adjusting views based on breakpoints. This is good place to start. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/layout/breakpoints.ts

Comment: Office itself does not provide such an event. But if an ordinary web application can detect a window size change, then it should work in an Office add-in too.